# What would be a fair day rate for a 1-day excavation job involving 1 person and a 24" bucket excavator?

Tags: contractors, excavation

We're hiring a local company to come move dirt around our 1/10 of an acre property in a small town. The job will be 1-day of work, all by machine (no hand-digging). What would be a normal rate to hire an excavation contractor for a 1-day job involving one person and a 24" bucket excavator? No materials and no waste removal (all the dirt will be dumped on-site).

Comment: Sorry, but cost questions are off topic here. They're volatile and regional.

Comment: That said, how much dirt can you have on a tenth of an acre? I'd hire a local teenager with a shovel and a wheel barrow, or rent a mini-hoe and have some fun.

Comment: Remember you are paying for the skilled person and the machine, fuel, maintenance, licenses and insurance.  Smaller machine might cost less, but take longer than a bigger machine.  Get a few quotes from different local companies, most should be near the same.

Comment: So how do you value you doing the work taking 2 days as you have little experiece compared to 1 day of a skilled person who won’t bust something else at the same time?

Comment: Just wondering if other people are willing to post thoughts on how much they've paid, even if it's in different areas or not exactly the same situation. We've contacted lots of companies, but so far only been able to get 1 estimate at $3200. I couldn't tell if he was blue-skying it.

Comment: We will pay what we're asked for a professional. Part of the job will be dredging a 100' long x 5' wide stormwater drainage ditch filled sediment, part will be putting downspouts underground.

Comment: The proper way to get an answer to your question is to ask a few contractors to come out and **give you an estimate based on what they can see by actually being there and talking to you**. Fair is a relative term.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about cost of services

Comment: there's no way that we can guess how tricky the digging will be, the contractor will be able to give you an estimate of how much dirt thet can move per hour.

Comment: If just the digging, no other work or supplies, that does seem high.  If fill and/or other stuff is included, that will be different, but straight digging of dirt would expect half of that at higher end.

Comment: @crip659 see other comments from the OP - mention of downspouts...

Comment: @Solar Mike  Saw that and something about fill, but also OP mentioned it was just digging without materials in question.

Answer (score 1):

Price is going to depend on many factors that vary by location.

Call several different local contractors, pick the one you like best.

Get the biggest machine you can fit on the site, eg: a 4 foot bucket holds 8 times as much dirt as a 2 foot bucket, so it can turn a 1 day job into a 1 hour job.